# Android ScrollView causes items disappear

Tags: android, scrollview, popupwindow

I have the following layout to show a popup:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ppba_dimmer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/dimming"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/ppba_llPopup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="@drawable/popup_bg">

            <!-- HEADER: Titol del Popup-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#10bcc9"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="12dip"
                android:text="@string/ppfa_tvTitolPopup" />

            <!-- Linia-->
            <View 
               android:background="#10bcc9" 
               android:layout_height="2dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <!-- Pais i Ciutat-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/ppfa_tvPaisCiutat" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/ppba_spPaisos"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/ppba_spCiutats"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

            ....
                        (i crop it, just because it's too long)

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This layout looks like as follows:

it seems that i'm not allowed to post images, so i let you the link, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7njC.png)

I realized that in some device screen the popup gets cropped because it's too long. So i decided to add a Scrollview like this (after the second LinearLayout, actually the popup window):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ppba_dimmer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dimming"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ppba_llPopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/popup_bg">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

                <!-- HEADER: Titol del Popup-->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="15dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:text="@string/ppfa_tvTitolPopup" />

                <!-- Linia-->
                <View 
                   android:background="#10bcc9" 
                   android:layout_height="2dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                   android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

                <!-- Pais i Ciutat-->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="@string/ppfa_tvPaisCiutat" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/ppba_spPaisos"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/ppba_spCiutats"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the layout looks like this:

Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLpw3.png)

I've tried different "layout_width" each one of them give me weird results. I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong, but i'm not able to figure out what. Could you please point me in the good direction?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you have two LinearLayout one inside the other?

Comment: the first one is bigger than the second, and it has an alpha black background, i achieve the dim effect this way.

Comment: suggestion: use an AlertDialog for the pop-up and let the system do the title and the dim for you.

Comment: thanks, i will check it. Anyway i'm still not clear on why it has this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is just because the linear layout before the   `<!-- HEADER: Titol del Popup-->` don't have the attribute:

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Hey, you nailed it!! i thought i already tried it, but it seems not. I add it to the scrollView and the linearLayout.

Thanks!